# JavaScript - replace to English number

Tags: javascript

I want to replace Bengali numbers to English numbers. such as

```
 var bengali = [০,১,২,৩,৪,৫,৬,৭,৮,৯];
 var eng = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
```

`bengali.replace(eng);`

So that anyone write any bengali number it convert to english number. How can I achieve this?

Comment: use `keyDown` event for the textbox and replace these characters when they are being entered.

Comment: @Krishna event is not my issue. I want to convert Bengali digit to english digit

Comment: You shouldn't even need the `eng` array in this case . . . those numbers match the array indexes exactly.  E.g., `bengali[0] = ০`, `bengali[1] = ১`, `bengali[2] = ২`, `bengali[3] = ৩`, etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have two options, depending on how maintainable you want the code to be.

I would recommend using a hash, keyed by Bengali number, and replacing with the value:

```js
var numbers = {
  '০': 0,
  '১': 1,
  '২': 2,
  '৩': 3,
  '৪': 4,
  '৫': 5,
  '৬': 6,
  '৭': 7,
  '৮': 8,
  '৯': 9
};

function replaceNumbers(input) {
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
    if (numbers.hasOwnProperty(input[i])) {
      output.push(numbers[input[i]]);
    } else {
      output.push(input[i]);
    }
  }
  return output.join('');
}

document.getElementById('r').textContent = replaceNumbers('৯  ৭  ৩');
```

```html
<pre id=r></pre>
```

If, for some reason, that isn't possible then you can use two arrays and a similar technique to map between them.

Answer (score 9):

A simple short method to convert Bengali numbers to the equivalent Arabic (English) numbers in Javascript is the following onliner function.

It will also convert Bengali numbers to Arabic in sentences leaving other text intact.

You can call the function on an "onkeyup" event to convert the text immediately.

```js
const toEn = n => n.replace(/[০-৯]/g, d => "০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯".indexOf(d));


// Tests
console.log(toEn("৬৭৮৯.৮৯"));                 //6789.89
console.log(toEn("The Number is: ৬৭৮৯.৮৯"));  //The Number is: 6789.89
console.log(toEn("০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯.৮৯"));          //0123456789.89
console.log(toEn("০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯"));              //0123456789
console.log(toEn("দাম ১২৩৪"));                  //দাম 1234
console.log(toEn("মোট ১২৩৪"));                 //মোট 1234
```

Updated to add the reverse of changing English (Arabic) numbers to Bengali. This is a shorter one-liner code:

```js
const toBn = n => n.replace(/\d/g, d => "০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯"[d])

// Tests
console.log(toBn("6789.89"));                 //৬৭৮৯.৮৯
console.log(toBn("The Number is: 6789.89"));  //The Number is: ৬৭৮৯.৮৯
console.log(toBn("0123456789.89"));           //০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯.৮৯
console.log(toBn("0123456789"));              //০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯
console.log(toBn("1234"));                    //১২৩৪
```

Comment: Hello, How do I convert English to Bangla

Comment: @AhmadSharif. Please see the updated code. Now both ways. Shorter one-liner for English to Bengali. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

You have everything that you need with just the `bengali` array (though, you need to wrap each character in quotes) and the built in `Array` method `indexOf()`.  This code demonstrates it:

```
var bengali = ["০", "১", "২", "৩", "৪", "৫", "৬", "৭", "৮", "৯"];

console.log(bengali.indexOf("০"));  // index is: 0
console.log(bengali.indexOf("১"));  // index is: 1
console.log(bengali.indexOf("২"));  // index is: 2
console.log(bengali.indexOf("৩"));  // index is: 3
console.log(bengali.indexOf("৪"));  // index is: 4
console.log(bengali.indexOf("৫"));  // index is: 5
console.log(bengali.indexOf("৬"));  // index is: 6
console.log(bengali.indexOf("৭"));  // index is: 7
console.log(bengali.indexOf("৮"));  // index is: 8
console.log(bengali.indexOf("৯"));  // index is: 9
```

So, all you have to do in your `replace` function is to return the index of the character that you are checking.

Answer (score 2):

This is also a good solution.

```
    const convertBanglaToEnglishNumber=(str)=>{
    let banglaNumber= 
        {'০': 0,
        '১': 1,
        '২': 2,
        '৩': 3,
        '৪': 4,
        '৫': 5,
        '৬': 6,
        '৭': 7,
        '৮': 8,
        '৯': 9}
    for (var x in banglaNumber) {
        str = str.replace(new RegExp(x, 'g'), banglaNumber[x]);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Everybody's answers was workable. But javascript does not compare with direct bangla numbers. You should use below array for bangla to english conversion

```
var numbers = {
        "\u09E6" : 0,
        "\u09E7" : 1,
        "\u09E8" : 2,
        "\u09E9" : 3,
        "\u09EA" : 4,
        "\u09EB" : 5,
        "\u09EC" : 6,
        "\u09ED" : 7,
        "\u09EE" : 8,
        "\u09EF" : 9
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

working code in AJS

## In Views:

```
<h1>{{replaceNumbersE2B('123.456908')}}</h1>
<h1>{{replaceNumbersB2E('৪৫৬.৯০৮')}}</h1>
```

## In ctrl:

```
$scope.testNumber = "";
        var numbersB = {
            '০': 0,
            '১': 1,
            '২': 2,
            '৩': 3,
            '৪': 4,
            '৫': 5,
            '৬': 6,
            '৭': 7,
            '৮': 8,
            '৯': 9
        };

        $scope.replaceNumbersB2E = function (input) {
            var output = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
                if (numbersB.hasOwnProperty(input[i])) {
                    output.push(numbersB[input[i]]);
                } else {
                    output.push(input[i]);
                }
            }
            return output.join('');
        }

        //$scope.testNumber = $scope.replaceNumbersB2E('৯৭৩');



        var numbersE = {
            0:'০',
            1:'১',
            2:'২',
            3:'৩',
            4:'৪',
            5:'৫',
            6:'৬',
            7:'৭',
            8:'৮',
            9:'৯'
        };

        $scope.replaceNumbersE2B = function (input) {
            var output = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
                if (numbersE.hasOwnProperty(input[i])) {
                    output.push(numbersE[input[i]]);
                } else {
                    output.push(input[i]);
                }
            }
            return output.join('');
        }

        $scope.testNumber = $scope.replaceNumbersE2B('111.65666');
        alert($scope.testNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

**English to Bengali number**

1,2,3... convert to ১,২,৩.... using pipe(angular) or filter(angularjs)

Example for angular:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'englishToBanglaNumber'
})

export class EnglishToBanglaNumberPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {

    var finalEnlishToBanglaNumber = {
      '0': '০', '1': '১', '2': '২', '3': '৩', '4': '৪', '5': '৫', '6': '৬', '7': '৭', '8': '৮', '9': '৯'
    };
    var retStr = value;
    for (var x in finalEnlishToBanglaNumber) {
      retStr = retStr.replace(new RegExp(x, 'g'), finalEnlishToBanglaNumber[x]);
    }
    return retStr;
  }
}
```

using in component.html

```
 <b>{{"123" | englishToBanglaNumber}}</b>
```

**result: ১২৩**

example for angularjs

```
app.filter('englishToBanglaNumber', [function () {
    return function (text) {
        var finalEnlishToBanglaNumber = {
            '0': '০', '1': '১', '2': '২', '3': '৩', '4': '৪', '5': '৫', '6': '৬', '7': '৭', '8': '৮', '9': '৯'
        };
        String.prototype.getDigitBanglaFromEnglish = function () {
            var retStr = this;
            for (var x in finalEnlishToBanglaNumber) {
                retStr = retStr.replace(new RegExp(x, 'g'), finalEnlishToBanglaNumber[x]);
            }
            return retStr;
        }; 

        return text.getDigitBanglaFromEnglish();
    };
}]);
```

> if you convert Bengali to english just modify the replace mesthod

```
retStr.replace(new RegExp(finalEnlishToBanglaNumber[x], 'g'), x);
```