# Convert Hindu–Arabic numerals to English numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, data-conversion, template-strings

Inside array there is non english number as string I want convert to english and put it into logic, and perform template string operation forEach div.

Here is sample of my code

```
const bigdata = [{img:'http://anything/com/123.png',title:'डेंजर ऑफर', inv:'१७५०'}] //Here १७५० = 1750 NOTE: I have multiple objects like this in my code

let template='';
bigdata.forEach(offers => {
function offer_tag(){
    if((HERE I WANT CONVERTED NUMBER)<15000){
       return `<span class="badge badge-warning">नवीन</span>`
    }
}

//This offer tag will be used in template string
```

I have got a conversion code from jQuery but I am very confused how can I use this code to convert string number to English number and use inside if statement. Here is jQuery code: (I copied from [JavaScript - replace to English number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30629242/jquery-replace-to-english-number))

```
    var numbers = {
      '०': 0,
      '१': 1,
      '२': 2,
      '३': 3,
      '४': 4,
      '५': 5,
      '६': 6,
      '७': 7,
      '८': 8,
      '९': 9
    };

    function replaceNumbers(input) {
      var output = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
        if (numbers.hasOwnProperty(input[i])) {
          output.push(numbers[input[i]]);
        } else {
          output.push(input[i]);
        }
      }
      return output.join('');
    }

    document.getElementById('r').textContent = replaceNumbers('१७५०');
```

Comment: is this question about converting a number or about iterating through an array of objects and apply some logic after converting to number? where should the result, in the second case, go? please add some HTML part to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Typically, you can just use `if (+replaceNumbers(offers.inv) < 15000) {`, however, there are several issues. First of all, the given code looks very odd, why are you declaring a function inside of the arrow function for `forEach` (the remaining code or closing `}` are not given, so i cannot tell)? Secondly, `replaceNumbers` simply replaces, and there is no error handling, should the string contain non-number symbols, e.g. `"१७hello५०"`. Last but least, `replaceNumbers` is way shorter to write with `const replaceNumbers = s => s.replace(/[०१२३४५६७८९]/g, m => numbers[m]);`.

Answer (score 1):

You could generate new objects with converted properties, if possible.

```js
function replaceNumbers(input) {
    var numbers = { '०': '0', '१': '1', '२': '2', '३': '3', '४': '4', '५': '5', '६': '6', '७': '7', '८': '8', '९': '9' };
    return Array.from(input, c => numbers[c] || c).join('');
}

const
    bigdata = [{img:'http://anything/com/123.png',title:'डेंजर ऑफर', inv:'१७५०'}],
    converted = bigdata.map(o => Object.assign(...Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: replaceNumbers(v) }))))

console.log(converted);
```

Comment: I think this is great, but I also think the original question needed the "integer" version of the number not the just the translated string.  I think you can simply pass your current result to `parseInt()`.  If you update your answer, mine will be redundant.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is very close already.  Try:

```js
function parseIntHindi(text, radix){
  var numbers = { '०': 0, '१': 1, '२': 2, '३': 3, '४': 4, '५': 5, '६': 6, '७': 7, '८': 8, '९': 9 };

  function replaceNumbers(input) {
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
      if (numbers.hasOwnProperty(input[i])) {
        output.push(numbers[input[i]]);
      } else {
        output.push(input[i]);
      }
    }
    return output.join('');
  }

  return parseInt(replaceNumbers(text), radix)
}

console.log(parseIntHindi("१७५०"));
console.log(parseIntHindi("१७५०") +1);
```